# Finding closest to the arbitrary chosen one sat valuation of formula

Tags: algorithm, logic, sat

Is there any algorithm with good performance (other than naive) finding the new, different valuation of formula closest to the arbitrary good valuation (known to us) of the formula?

F.e.

((p & q & x) | r) <-> ( a & b & c & d & e) correct valuation p,q,x = 1, r = 0, a..e = 1. Change of f.e. a to 0 is not good for us- it forces to change p,q,x = 0. The change of "r" is better for us - we do not have to change anything from r. We can assume that "closest" means closest according to the hamming metric.

This algorithm would be quite useful for my program exploring space of states generated from temporal logic formula (too big graph for all solutions with > 15 variables, many possible valuations, only partial search with BFS algorithm).